# Destroy dialog after closing it - jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to know if there's any way we can destroy a dialog after closing it.
And the reason is : I have a dialog with *dynamic content* where I add text and buttons.
When I **first** open the dialog, the elements are styled properly with the jQuery Mobile theme (e.g. buttons), but... when I close it and then reopen it the **second** time, always with dynamic content, elements are **NOT** styled with jQM theme, just normal navigator-styled elements.

#### Possible explanation :

At first, when the dialog isn't yet initialized, you can insert whatever elements you want in it, and then in the initialization process, jQuery Mobile stylize the elements accordingly. And when you close the dialog, it is possible that it isn't completely destroyed and so when you try to open it, it doesn't initialize the elements.

How can I destroy the dialog and remove it completely from the DOM before opening it again ?

Comment: try this `$(document).on('pagehide', '#dialog', function () { $(this).remove(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is trigger `create` on the dialog after editing its content, and *then* open it :

```
$('#deviceHistoryDialog').trigger('create');
$('#linkOpenHistoryDialog').click();
```